# KendoUI filters and paging functionality - How they work with large JSON data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have 100,000 records right now (will grow in future). I have JSON api call (remote URL, however, within same server) to get those records. If I use KendoUI with paging turned on (say 50 per page), will KendoUI datasource going to fetch all those records and bring them into client and apply paging? Or is it something I need to pass to the server (page size) to be able to only get only needed data for display? If I need to pass, do I have to write custom data source query methods?

Same question goes for using filter input boxes in toolbar within KendoUI.

Comment: I found answer in another thread that one way to solve this issue is - we can do lazy loading by doing scrolling "virtual = true". However, my question still remains different as if I am calling a remote JSON API, how do I pass what page size to fetch and what page number I am on if I use transport mechanism as specified in KendoUI.

Comment: If you turn pagination on, KendoUI will grab the entire JSON response and apply pagination to it. I don't think there's an easy way for a pagination solution with lazy loading unless if you modify their src code or attach events to their previous and next page buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two (efficient) ways of loading that amount of data:

1. Setting [`serverPaging`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-serverPaging) to true in the `DataSource`definition.
2. Using `serverPaging` plyst (as @bobosov534 and @gitsitgo suggests) [`virtual`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-scrollable.virtual) scrolling.

In the both you receive in the server tow parameters: `top` indicating the number of records to retrieve (what you have defined as `pageSize`) and `skip` for the number of records to ignore (no `skip` means the first `top` records).

The difference is that int the first you see a pagination bar in the bottom of the grid and in the second you see additional records as you scroll down.

In [`DataSource.serverPaging`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-serverPaging) you find detailed information on the fields sent to the server for managing pagination.